# Is there a difference between checking for inequality (!==) against undefined and null and just checking for corcive inequality (!=) against null?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

If I pass a variable to the existential operator in Coffescript it is converted to a pair of `!==` comparisons:

```
            compiles to
Coffeescript ------> JS
a?                   typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null;
```

But if I use a literal or expression it instead uses a `!=` comparison:

```
            compiles to
Coffeescript ------> JS
17?                  17 != null;

//same thing for regexps, strings, function calls and other expressions
//as far as I know.
```

Is there any reason for preferring the double `!==`s over the shorter `!= null`, other then perhaps making JSLint happy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: They're behaviorally equivalent, and the `!= null` compilation is an optimization. Either way, `x?` means that `x` is neither `null` nor `undefined`.

People ask about this a lot on the CoffeeScript issue tracker. The reason `x != null` isn't used everywhere as the compiled output of `x?` is that `x != null` (or any other comparison against `x`) causes a runtime error if `x` doesn't exist. Try it on the Node REPL:

```
> x != null
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

By "doesn't exist," I mean no `var x`, no `window.x = ...`, and you're not in a function where `x` is the name of an argument. (The CoffeeScript compiler can't identify the `window.x` case because it doesn't make any assumptions about the environment you're in.) So unless there's a `var x` declaration or an argument named `x` in the current scope, the compiler has to use `typeof x !== "undefined"` to prevent your process from potentially crashing.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand why people find that confusing. In ECMAScript:

```
a?
```

is equivalent to:

```
typeof a !== 'undefined' && a !== undefined && a !== null && a !== 0 && a !== false && a !== '';
```

The Coffeescript refactoring to:

```
typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null;
```

means that:

```
var a = false;
a?;  // evaluates to true?
```

Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is true. ? is the existential operator. It is meant to indicate if the variable exists.

Comment: @RobG it makes sense for them to make a new operator. We already have `!!a` for falsy evaluation

Comment: @liammclennan — that test doesn't tell you anything about whether a variable exists or not, it just provides a hint about what its value isn't. @missingno — Overloading the `?` operator doesn't seem like a good idea, it's just shorthand and (to me) obfuscates the code.

Comment: @RobG sure it does. if a? then you know that the variable exists. if not a? then you know that either the variable has not been declared, it is null or it is undefined.

Comment: So you agree that a? doesn't tell you much. There is only one reason to test the value of a variable: to see if it fits some criteria such as Type (number, string, etc.) or within a range of values. You can't distinguish between declared and not assigned a value, or not declared at all (without using try..catch and hoping for a reference error to detect the latter) and should never be in a position to need to do so.

Comment: I find it useful. I have never felt the need to differentiate between not declared and declared but not assigned a value. In both cases the existential operator correctly tells me that I can't work with that value.

Comment: Nor have I, which is why I can't see the need for something that makes `null`, `undefined` and *not declared* a special category of their own. I guess someone has or had a need for that.